# Use gradle plugin in parent project's buildSrc

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-multi-project-build

How can a subproject in a multiproject Gradle build use a Gradle plugin that's defined in the root project's `buildSrc` folder?

I've basically got:

- settings.gradle
- buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com/example/conventions/JavaConventionsPlugin.groovy
- buildSrc/build.gradle
- common/build.gradle

and I'm trying to apply the plugin in the `common` project:

```
apply plugin: 'com.example.conventions.JavaConventionsPlugin'
```

but it says

> Plugin with id 'com.example.conventions.JavaConventionsPlugin' not
> found.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the plugin layout is different in `buildSrc` and I should have been following this example: https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html

- buildSrc/build.gradle
- buildSrc/settings.gradle
- buildSrc/src/main/groovy/example.java-conventions.gradle
- buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com/example/conventions/JavaConventionsPlugin.groovy

and applying using:

```
plugins {
    id 'example.java-conventions'
}
```